# hasManyThrough returning empty array

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I need some help with my hasManyThrough relationship

I have 3 tables:

```
Field Table
id

Submission Field Table
id
field_id

Submission Field Values Table
id
submission_field_id
```

and I'm trying to get all the SubmissionFieldValue for the Field through SubmissionField with this:

```
public function FieldValues() {
    return $this->hasManyThrough(SubmissionFieldValues::class, SubmissionField::class, 'id', 'submission_field_id', 'id', 'form_field_id');
}
```

So my logic is:
Match Field's `id` to Submission Field's `field_id` then use those Submission Fields' id to match with Submission Field Value's `submission_field_id` and return all of those SubmissionFieldValues.

I'm not entirely sure why this doesn't return anything. It's not throwing an error either when I run it so I'm guessing it's just an issue with my key/parameter ordering.

Thank you for any and all help!

Answer (score 0):

The relation you are looking for is:

```
public function fieldValues() {
    return $this->hasManyThrough(SubmissionFieldValues::class, 
    SubmissionField::class, 'field_id', 'submission_field_id', 'id');
}
```

And to retrieve the values:

```
return $object->fieldValues;
```

Comment: This ended up returning values for me in the relationship, but they were the wrong values.

Answer (score 0):

[Has Many Through](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through)

Let's look at the tables required to define this relationship:

```
countries
    id - integer
    name - string

users
    id - integer
    country_id - integer
    name - string

posts
    id - integer
    user_id - integer
    title - string
```

If you would like to customize the keys of the relationship, you may pass them as the third and fourth arguments to the hasManyThrough method. The third argument is the name of the foreign key on the intermediate model. The fourth argument is the name of the foreign key on the final model. The fifth argument is the local key, while the sixth argument is the local key of the intermediate model:

```
class Country extends Model
{
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(
            'App\Models\Post',
            'App\Models\User',
            'country_id', // Foreign key on users table...
            'user_id', // Foreign key on posts table...
            'id', // Local key on countries table...
            'id' // Local key on users table...
        );
    }
}
```